# How can I achieve a similar result to a SQL SUM and GROUP BY query in JavaScript and ReactJS for an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, group

Filtering and Summing Specific Object Values in Array

I have an interesting problem to solve. I am working on a ReactJS component. I have an array of objects as follows:

[Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-moon-3zyhkc?file=/src/App.js)

```
const frames = [
{
ProjectName: "Blue",
EmployeeGroup: false,
Amount: 50,
Hours: 15,
ProjectType: "Romeo",
},
{
ProjectName: "Red",
EmployeeGroup: false,
Amount: 20,
Hours: 5,
ProjectType: "Lima",
},
{
ProjectName: "Green",
EmployeeGroup: true,
Amount: 40,
Hours: 10,
ProjectType: "Lima",
}
]
```

The idea is to sum the Amount and Hours for the different ProjectType values and ignore the EmployeeGroup value as it is irrelevant. So the end result would ideally be an object that has the following key value pairs:

```
{
ProjectType: "Lima",
TotalAmount: 60,
TotalHours: 15,
},
{
ProjectType: "Romeo",
TotalAmount: 50,
TotalHours: 15,
}
```

In SQL this is fairly straightforward, as one could simply do a SUM(TotalAmount) and SUM(TotalHours) and GROUP BY ProjectType. I want to achieve something similar in JavaScript but have been unsuccessful thus far.

I have tried the array.filter and array.reduce methods to try to achieve the desired result. My code looks like this:

```
const filterByProjectType = (array, projectType) => {
     const reducer = (array) => {
          const reduced = array.reduce(
               (accumulator, currentVal) => accumulator + currentVal.Amount, 0
          );
          return reduced;
     }
     const filtered = reduced(array.filter((item) => item.ProjectType.includes(projectType)));
     return filtered
}

console.log(filterByProjectType(frames, "Lima"))
```

This currently gives me the value of 60 which is the desired and correct value of TotalAmount of the ProjectType Lima. I know I could repeat this process and then compile the results into an object, but as usual, I believe a quicker way exists, maybe using the array.group() or something similar. What do you recommend to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create the final object first...

```
const items = {};
frames.forEach( ({ProjectType, Amount, Hours}) => {
  if(!items[ProjectType]){
    items[ProjectType] = {ProjectType, TotalAmount: 0, TotalHours: 0};
  }
  items[ProjectType].TotalAmount += Amount;
  items[ProjectType].TotalHours += Hours;
});
const output = Object.values(items);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This answer works! So simple too. Seems like that forEach is the way to go to iterate through the objects. Thank you @PJaoko.

Comment: You're welcome :)
forEach is my usually my first go to tool for anything array related.